# MouseMoved is not fired after MousePressed in Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Am trying to implement a drag like behavior that allows a user to draw a line.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    int index = clickedBall(e.getX(),e.getY());
    if(index!=-1){
        MainWindow.inFocusBall = index;
        lx1 = TestPlay.balls.get(index).getX()+TestPlay.balls.get(index).getRadius()/2;
        ly1 = TestPlay.balls.get(index).getY()+TestPlay.balls.get(index).getRadius()/2;
        System.out.println("Line Start:"+lx1+","+ly1);  
        BallProp.update();
    }
    isPressed = true;
    drawLine = true;
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    if(isPressed){
    System.out.println("MouseMoved");
    int index = MainWindow.inFocusBall;
    if(index!=-1){
        MainWindow.inFocusBall = index;
        lx1 = TestPlay.balls.get(index).getX()+TestPlay.balls.get(index).getRadius()/2;
        ly1 = TestPlay.balls.get(index).getY()+TestPlay.balls.get(index).getRadius()/2;
        BallProp.update();
    }
    lx2 = e.getX();
    ly2 = e.getY();
    repaint();
    }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    isPressed = false;
    drawLine = false;
    System.out.println("MouseRelased");
    //TestPlay.balls.get(MainWindow.inFocusBall);
}
```

the output of this code is MousePressed -> MouseRelased.

More Details (if you understand the code don't read).

The idea here is that when the mouse is pressed it calculates if its pressed over a graphics object (Ball in this case), if so it sets the index (index in balls array) to the ball that was pressed on, it also sets the start of the line that will be drawn from the center of the circle to it's coordinates.

on Mouse moved if isPressed is true it sets the flag drawLine to true (it's used by the paint component to draw the line), the line is drawn from the center of the ball to the current mouse position, upon mouse release the drawline and ispressed are set to false.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawBalls(g);
    if(drawLine){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(lx1, ly1, lx2, ly2);
    }
}

public void drawBalls(Graphics g){
    for(int x=0;x<TestPlay.balls.size();x++){
        g.setColor(TestPlay.balls.get(x).getColor());
        g.fillOval(TestPlay.balls.get(x).getX(), TestPlay.balls.get(x).getY(), TestPlay.balls.get(x).getRadius(), TestPlay.balls.get(x).getRadius());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you implement the mouseDragged() event? That gets fired when you click and drag within the component.

Comment: I tried it this way but it caused a bug in the program.

Comment: one Question though, does mouse pressed and mouse released are fired before and after the mouseDragged()?

Comment: Yes they do. Why can't you implement mouseDragged()?

Comment: Cause the mousePressed() doesn't get fired before it.

Comment: I believe it does: 
mousePressed
mouseDragged: 108 , 90
mouseDragged: 109 , 90
...
mouseDragged: 195 , 106
mouseDragged: 197 , 106
mouseDragged: 198 , 106
mouseReleased

Comment: i found out the bug that caused the mouseDragged issue, i think i can fix it now. Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

You should try implementing mouseDragged():

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("mouseDragged: " + e.getX() + " , " + e.getY());

}
```